# Overlay Swing Text Label as Text is Entered

Tags: java, swing, label, overlay

Various forms in my program use JTables for which I've been able to use a Key Listener to select a row as the user types.  This works great but I would like to provide some feedback to the user to show what text is being entered.

I've tried creating frame/labels but can't get them to show correctly.

My basic thoughts were - create the frame (if it doesn't already exist), create the label and set the text. Eg:

```
private void showSearchLabel(String search) {
    if (null == searchTextFrame) {
        searchTextFrame = new JFrame("searchTextFrame");
        searchTextFrame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        searchTextFrame.setUndecorated(true);
        searchTextFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        searchTextFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
        searchTextLabel = new JLabel();
        searchTextFrame.getContentPane().add(searchTextLabel);
        searchTextFrame.pack();
        searchTextFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    searchTextLabel.setText(search);

}
```

showSearchLabel is called by a Key Listener which adds the most recent key press to the search string. Backspace clears the string (and removes the frame/label).  Enter key selects the item in the table and should also remove the frame/label.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** Clarification - using the code above, nothing shows at all.

If I set the text when creating the label, the first character is visible (which is to be expected as at that point, the user has only typed one character).  Calling *.setText(search)* after this point, the text is not updated.  Note - this is visible in the very top/left hand corner of the screen, which is not really where I want it (ideally, would like it to show within the JTable).

Comment: Can you clarify your question..."can't get them to show correctly" is a fairly broad statement to the problem.

Comment: I've amended the question, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had to repeat something like this a number of times over the last few months, using a verity of different UI approaches (hiding a field till the user typed and then making it visible via a `BorderLayout`; a static field on the screen; etc...) and was attempting to build a more concise and re-usable library mechanism which would allow me to configure any `JTable` with easy filterable support.

One of the reasons I use a `JTextField` over a `JLabel`, is it handles user input better then anything you or I might be able to produce (in a reasonable amount of time), but that's me ;)

Personally, I prefer not to open any new windows, as this can introduce other issues, like focus related issues as well as the window been hidden behind the current window on some platforms, etc.

Equally, the few times I've "unhidden" a field, the layout is forced to change, which can look ugly and there isn't always a need to have the filter field visible all the time.  Instead, what I was trying to achieve was a "popup" field which appeared inline with with table itself, but would be capable of been made visible anywhere within the viewable area of the parent `JScrollPane`...

Now, this approach may not suit your needs, but it's what I've been work towards...

[image: Filter]

Again, the core concept was to provide functionality that didn't require me to extend a `JTable`, but could wrapped around an existing `JTable`.  The core functionality is provided by a utility class and is managed through two `interfaces` which provide externalized control over some of the core functionality (how the filter is applied to the `JTable` and how a cancel operation works).  The utility class also provides the means to configure what keyboard action will cancel the filter field

The `JTextField` which is displayed, is actually added to the `JTable` itself.  I had thought about trying to force a "offset" into the view, so all the rows were pushed down, but the only way I know how to do this is to extend the `JTable` itself, which is what I was trying to avoid

```
public class TableUtilities {

    private static WeakHashMap<JTable, FilterSupport> mapFilters = new WeakHashMap(25);

    public static void installFilterSupport(JTable table, IFilterListener listener, KeyStroke escapeKey) {
        FilterSupport support = new FilterSupport(table, listener, escapeKey);
        mapFilters.put(table, support);
    }

    public static void uninstallFilterSupport(JTable table) {
        FilterSupport support = mapFilters.remove(table);
        if (support != null) {
            support.uninstall();
        }
    }

    protected static class FilterSupport implements IFilterSupport {

        private JViewport viewport;
        private JTable table;
        private JTextField searchField;
        private Timer filterTimer;

        private HierarchyListener hierarchyListener;
        private ChangeListener changeListener;
        private IFilterListener filterListener;

        public FilterSupport(JTable table, IFilterListener listener, KeyStroke escapeKey) {
            this.table = table;
            this.filterListener = listener;
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

            hierarchyListener = new HierarchyListener() {
                @Override
                public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e) {
                    long flags = e.getChangeFlags();
                    if ((flags & HierarchyEvent.PARENT_CHANGED) != 0) {
                        if (e.getChanged().equals(table)) {
                            JTable table = (JTable) e.getChanged();
                            if (e.getChangedParent() instanceof JViewport) {
                                if (table.getParent() == null) {
                                    uninstall();
                                } else {
                                    install();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            changeListener = new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    JViewport viewport = (JViewport) e.getSource();
                    Rectangle viewRect = viewport.getViewRect();
                    searchField.setSize(searchField.getPreferredSize());
                    int x = (viewRect.x + viewRect.width) - searchField.getWidth();
                    int y = viewRect.y;
                    searchField.setLocation(x, y);
                }
            };

            table.addHierarchyListener(hierarchyListener);

            searchField = new JTextField(20);
            searchField.setVisible(false);
            searchField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    filterChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    filterChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    filterChanged();
                }
            });

            searchField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                    cancelField();
                }
            });

            filterTimer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    applyFilter();
                }
            });
            filterTimer.setRepeats(false);

            table.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                    if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(e.getKeyChar())) {
                        searchField.setVisible(true);
                        table.revalidate();
                        table.repaint();
                        // ?? Should this maintain the current filter value?
                        searchField.setText(null);
                        searchField.requestFocusInWindow();
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                searchField.dispatchEvent(e);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }

            });

            Action escapeAction = new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    cancelField();
                }
            };

            bindKeyStrokeTo(table, JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED, "clear", escapeKey, escapeAction);
            bindKeyStrokeTo(searchField, JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED, "clear", escapeKey, escapeAction);

        }

        protected void cancelField() {
            searchField.setVisible(false);
            table.requestFocusInWindow();
            table.revalidate();
            table.repaint();
            if (filterListener != null) {
                filterListener.filterCancelled(table, this);
            }
        }

        public void filterChanged() {
            filterTimer.restart();
        }

        protected void applyFilter() {

            if (filterListener != null) {
                filterListener.filterChanged(table, searchField.getText());
            }

        }

        protected void uninstall() {
            filterTimer.stop();
            if (viewport != null) {
                if (changeListener != null) {
                    viewport.removeChangeListener(changeListener);
                }
                table.remove(searchField);
                searchField.setVisible(false);
            }
            viewport = null;
        }

        protected void install() {
            if (viewport != null) {
                uninstall();
            }
            Container parent = table.getParent();
            if (parent instanceof JViewport) {
                viewport = (JViewport) parent;
                viewport.addChangeListener(changeListener);
                table.add(searchField);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getFilter() {
            return searchField.getText();
        }

        @Override
        public void setFilter(String filter) {
            searchField.setText(filter);
        }

    }

    public static void bindKeyStrokeTo(JComponent parent, int condition, String name, KeyStroke keyStroke, Action action) {
        InputMap im = parent.getInputMap(condition);
        ActionMap am = parent.getActionMap();

        im.put(keyStroke, name);
        am.put(name, action);
    }

    public static interface IFilterSupport {

        public String getFilter();

        public void setFilter(String filter);

    }

    public static interface IFilterListener {

        public void filterChanged(JTable table, String filter);

        public void filterCancelled(JTable table, IFilterSupport support);
    }

}
```

And my test class...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class TestSearchTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSearchTable();
    }

    public TestSearchTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
                            new Object[][]{
                                {"Tiana", "Wilmer"},
                                {"Twana", "Wingate"},
                                {"Cody", "Baumgarten"},
                                {"Venus", "Espy"},
                                {"Savanna", "Buckmaster"},
                                {"Adrien", "Edgecomb"},
                                {"Lauretta", "Sassman"},
                                {"Vivienne", "Glasco"},
                                {"Cassy", "Merryman"},
                                {"Mitchel", "Jarvie"},
                                {"Kelsi", "Casebeer"},
                                {"Rosy", "Rizzi"},
                                {"Bernice", "Capote"},
                                {"Tijuana", "Launius"},
                                {"Jeffie", "Crownover"},
                                {"Selena", "Leavy"},
                                {"Damon", "Tulloch"},
                                {"Norris", "Devitt"},
                                {"Cecil", "Burgio"},
                                {"Queen", "Mechling"}},
                            new Object[]{"First Name", "Last name"}
            ) {

                @Override
                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                    return false;
                }

            };

            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
            TableUtilities.installFilterSupport(table,
                            new TableUtilities.IFilterListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void filterChanged(JTable table, String filter) {
                                    TableRowSorter sorter = (TableRowSorter) table.getRowSorter();
                                    if (filter == null || filter.trim().length() == 0) {
                                        filter = "*";
                                    }

                                    if (!filter.startsWith("*") || !filter.endsWith("*")) {
                                        filter = "*" + filter + "*";
                                    }
                                    filter = wildcardToRegex(filter);
                                    filter = "(?i)" + filter;
                                    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(filter));
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void filterCancelled(JTable table, TableUtilities.IFilterSupport support) {
//                                  support.setFilter(null);
                                }
                            },
                            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0));
            add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }

    }

    public static String wildcardToRegex(String wildcard) {

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(wildcard.length());
        s.append('^');

        for (int i = 0, is = wildcard.length(); i < is; i++) {

            char c = wildcard.charAt(i);
            switch (c) {
                case '*':
                    s.append(".*");
                    break;
                case '?':
                    s.append(".");
                    break;
                // escape special regexp-characters
                case '(':
                case ')':
                case '[':
                case ']':
                case '$':
                case '^':
                case '.':
                case '{':
                case '}':
                case '|':
                case '\\':
                    s.append("\\");
                    s.append(c);
                    break;
                default:
                    s.append(c);
                    break;
            }

        }

        s.append('$');
        return (s.toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm looking for.  The filter is maybe overkill for some of my lists but will be ideal for the larger lists.  I'm having a play around and have it working on a new frame/panel.  Not yet on my existing table... possibly due to modality issues.

Comment: Well, the API is designed to allow you to decide "how" to respond to changes in the text that the user enters.

Comment: I've gone with this answer.  It provides all the functionality I need and has made me rethink how I'm creating the list forms.  Thanks.

Comment: Any tips on handling other key events? For example - previously escape would cancel my form, returning to the parent and enter would select the item, returning the value to the parent.  I've unbound the table and escape key so escape now works as expected but how would I handle the enter key?

Comment: You could expand the "IFilterListener" to provided a "filterAccepted" or "filterActionPerofrmed" which could be called when the "searchField"'s ActionListener is triggered, as an idea. Currently, the escape key should only be localised to the table and field while they have focus, I'd at least leave the field bound, or change the "clear" key stroke, which you have control over, but that's up to you

Comment: Another idea (to allow dismissal of the field) is to use something like the `BuddySupport` API from SwingLabs SwingX library to place a "close" button within the field itself, which could then dismiss the field.  You could, instead of showing just a `JTextField`, show a `JPanel` with the field and "close" button on it, like Chrome's search feature...as ideas...

Comment: Expanding the install filter method with a _selectKey_ and creating a _selectAction_ seems pretty natural.  The _selectAction_ selects the top row of the table and cancels the text field.  This then results in the filter cancelling (showing the original list with the correct item selected) and returning focus to the table.  Another enter key press selects the item and returns to the parent form.  Selecting items and data using the keyboard works well with this.  Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking of adding a "shouldStartFiltering" method that took an EventObject which wild allow you to control when the filter field should be shown, to add more customisability

Answer (score 2):

A new [`JLabel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) has "an empty string for the title." It's preferred size is zero. You can

- Add the required space in the constructor.

  ```
  searchTextLabel = new JLabel("        ");
  ```
- Invoke `pack()` on the enclosing frame, after the call to `setVisible()`.

  ```
  f.setVisible(true);
  …
  searchTextFrame.pack();
  ```
- Add a single space in the constructor, to establish the height, and invoke `validate()` on the enclosing `Container`.

  ```
  searchTextLabel = new JLabel(" ");
  …
  f.setVisible(true);
  …
  searchTextLabel.setText(search);
  searchTextLabel.validate();
  ```

Comment: Thanks - this seems pretty straight forward.  I'm working more towards MadProgrammer's answer as the filter will be beneficial for some of my larger lists.