# how to filter jTable using textField

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i doing a netbeans project which has a jTable1,filter and jButtonGo..
my jTable is connected to mysql database .. iJust want to filter data on jTable11 using filtertextFiled and Go Button if possible.

Comment: Also take a look at [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: Or, if you're really feeling brave, have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500713/overlay-swing-text-label-as-text-is-entered/29506154#29506154)