# how can i transparent my JTextField and JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlabel, jtextfield

My `JTextField` and `JLabel` are not Transparent in `JPanel` When `JTable` is visible it overlap between `JTextField` and `JLabel`. I want to show `JTable` when i Search something in Search (`JTextField`) but it overlap and `JTable` is not visible properly. Please Help here is my code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;

public class ButtonBarExample1 {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField Search;
    private JTable CategoryTable;
    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private static Connection con;
    private String query;
    private PreparedStatement PStat;
    private ResultSet res;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private int Enter=0;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel label_1;
    private JTextField CategoryID;
    private JTextField CategoryName;
    private JPanel panel_1;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String\[\] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    WebLookAndFeel.install();
                    ButtonBarExample1 window = new ButtonBarExample1();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public ButtonBarExample1() {
        initialize();
        con=Database.Database();
    }

    public void remove(){
        while(CategoryTable.getRowCount()>0) {
            model.removeRow(0);
        }
    }

    public void changed(){
        if(Search.getText().length()==0){
            panel.remove(scrollPane);
            panel.repaint();
            panel.revalidate(); 
        }else{
            try{
            panel.add(scrollPane);
            scrollPane.setViewportView(CategoryTable);
            remove();
            query="Select * from CategoryEntry where Category_Name like '"+Search.getText().trim()+"%'";
            PStat=con.prepareStatement(query);
            res=PStat.executeQuery();

            model=(DefaultTableModel)CategoryTable.getModel();
            model.setRowCount(0);
            CategoryTable.setRowHeight(30);

            while(res.next()){
                String CatID=res.getString("Category_ID");
                String CatName=res.getString("Category_Name");
                Object\[\] row= {CatID,CatName};
                model.addRow(row);
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                try{
                    PStat.close();
                    res.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 934, 601);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel();
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 917, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 562, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        panel.setLayout(null);

        Search = new JTextField();
        Search.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
                    changed();
                }
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
                    changed();
                }
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
                    changed();
                }
                });
        Search.setBounds(90, 11, 402, 31);
        panel.add(Search);
        Search.setColumns(10);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(90, 41, 402, 127);

        CategoryTable = new JTable();
        CategoryTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                int row=CategoryTable.getSelectedRow();
                String TableClicked=(CategoryTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0)).toString();

                try{
                query="Select * from CategoryEntry where Category_ID='"+TableClicked+"'";
                PStat=con.prepareStatement(query);
                res=PStat.executeQuery();

                if(res.next()){
                    String CatID=res.getString("Category_ID");
                    CategoryID.setText(CatID);
                    String CatName=res.getString("Category_Name");
                    CategoryName.setText(CatName);
                }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    try{
                        PStat.close();
                        res.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        CategoryTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object\[\]\[\] {
            },
            new String\[\] {
                "CategoryID", "CategoryName"
            }
        ));

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Search");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(21, 19, 46, 14);
        panel.add(lblNewLabel);

        panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBounds(31, 53, 317, 76);
        panel_1.setOpaque(false);
        panel.add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        label_1 = new JLabel("Category ID");
        label_1.setBounds(10, 14, 97, 18);
        panel_1.add(label_1);
        label_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));

        CategoryID = new JTextField();
        CategoryID.setBounds(117, 11, 157, 25);
        CategoryID.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,128));
        CategoryID.setOpaque(false);
        panel_1.add(CategoryID);
        CategoryID.setEditable(false);
        CategoryID.setColumns(10);

        label = new JLabel("Category Name");
        label.setBounds(10, 42, 97, 18);
        panel_1.add(label);
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));

        CategoryName = new JTextField();
        CategoryName.setBounds(117, 39, 157, 25);
        panel_1.add(CategoryName);
        CategoryName.setEditable(false);
        CategoryName.setColumns(10);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL0ZV.png)

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. We don't have access to your database so we can't run your code to see the described problem. So what you need to is just create a JTable using a DefaultTableModel with a specified number of rows/columns. Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: `panel.setLayout(null);` and `lblNewLabel.setBounds(21, 19, 46, 14);` might be the beginning of your problems.

Comment: Btw this code won't compile because of: `new Object\[\]\[\] {` please post a valid runnable example

Comment: [This is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500713/overlay-swing-text-label-as-text-is-entered/29506154#29506154) I some time ago which provides a `JTextField` display inline with the `JTable`, so that when the user starts typing it displays the `JTextField` onto of the `JTable` an filters the `JTable` in realtime

Comment: Or you can use the example from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting). Not only does it provide a working example with explanations, but you have a link to a Swing resource for future problems.

Comment: When ever you think you need `null` layouts you don't, expect those very few exceptions when you do, in which case, you actually don't, you're just to lazy to define a more appropriate approach. Your solution could be made simpler with the use of a `CardLayout` to switch between the vies

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. Actually I made scrollpane transparency to true and also make it viewport to transparency to true like this.

`scrollPane.setOpaque (true);`
`scrollPane.getViewPort ().setOpaque (true);`